# Using unProject correctly in Java Libgdx

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I want to make a button clickable, but it isn't working - it seems like I need to use `unproject()` but I can't figure out how. The code in question is:

```
Texture playButtonImage;
SpriteBatch batch;
ClickListener clickListener;
Rectangle playButtonRectangle;
Vector2 touchPos;
OrthographicCamera camera;

@Override
public void show() {
    playButtonImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("PlayButton.png"));

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    playButtonRectangle = new Rectangle();
    playButtonRectangle.x = 400;
    playButtonRectangle.y = 250;
    playButtonRectangle.width = 128;
    playButtonRectangle.height = 64;
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(playButtonImage, playButtonRectangle.x, playButtonRectangle.y);
    batch.end();

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2();
        touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());


        if (playButtonRectangle.contains(touchPos)) {
            batch.begin();
            batch.draw(playButtonImage, 1, 1);
            batch.end();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible that the screen coordinate (0,0) is in the top left, but the camera has coordinate (0,0) in the bottom left. What happens if you use Gdx.input.getY()*-1?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general you use `camera.unproject(Vector)` to transform your screen coordinates from a click or touch to your gameworld. This is needed because the origin is not necessarily the same and using the camera you can also zoom in and out, move around, rotate and so on. Unprojecting will take care of all of that and give you your game world coordinate matching the pointers position.

In your example it would go like this:

```
Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
camera.unproject(touchPos);
```

Having this said you should actually not do this UI task manually. Libgdx has also some shipped UI functionality which is called a `Stage` (see [this](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d)). There are lots of widgets already available (see [this](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2dui)). They use skins (you can get a basic one from [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data), you need all the uiskin.* files). They automatically forward inputevents to the socalled `Actors`, e.g. a button, and you just need to implement handling of those events.

Comment: As stated in my answer initializing a new Vector3 object on every frame when touched is introducing a lot of overhead. GC cycles are heavy especially on time critical applications like games (even worse on mobile; and libgdx is built for mobile too)

Comment: You can also use Pools to get around the problem of initializing a new Vector3.

Answer (score 4):

with camera.unproject(Vector3); you can translate screen coordinates to game world coordinates.

```
Vector3 tmpCoords = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
camera.unproject(tmpCoords);

tmpCoords.x //is now the touched X coordinate in the game world coordinate system
tmpCoords.y //is now the touched Y coordinate in the game world coordinate system.
```

In addition to that it is best practice to define a tmpVector as a field an Instantiate a Vector3 object only once. You can then do the same with the .set() method.

```
tmpCoords.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
camera.unproject(tmpCoords);

tmpCoords.x //is now the touched X coordinate in the game world coordinate system
tmpCoords.y //is now the touched Y coordinate in the game world coordinate system.
```

Therefore you reduce object creation and remove unnecessary GC calls which lead to microlag.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

camera.update();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

batch.begin();
batch.draw(playButtonImage, playButtonRectangle.x, playButtonRectangle.y);
batch.end();

if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
    Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
    touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(),0);
    camera.unproject(touchPos);


    if (playButtonRectangle.contains(touchPos.x, touchPos.y)) {
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(playButtonImage, 1, 1);
        batch.end();
    }
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

when ever u need a touch point from user and to convert those touchpoints to camera u need to unproject them to camera coordinates by camera coordinates

```
camera.unproject(touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
```