# Is this the right way to detect a touch on a rectangle in LibGdx ? Does not seem to be working for me

Tags: android, libgdx

This is the code for my gamescreen where i want burst my ballon when its touched .
orientation is portrait.
but it does not seem to work for me.

```
 public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    final BB game;
    private BitmapFont font;
    private static final int no_of_frames = 2;
    Texture ballonFrames;
    TextureRegion[] burstFrames = new TextureRegion[no_of_frames];
    Animation burstAnimation;
    Array<Rectangle> ballons;
    TextureRegion currentFrame;
    long lastBallonTime;
    int ballonBursted;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    int ballonMissed;

    Sound ballonBursting;

    public GameScreen(final BB gam) {
        this.game = gam;

        ballonFrames = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ballon_burst.png"));
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font.fnt"), false);
        ballonBursting = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files
                .internal("BallonBursting.wav"));
        TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(ballonFrames,
                ballonFrames.getWidth() / 2, ballonFrames.getHeight());
        burstFrames[0] = tmp[0][0];
        burstFrames[1] = tmp[0][1];

        burstAnimation = new Animation(3.0f, burstFrames);
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);

        ballons = new Array<Rectangle>();

        spawnBallon();

    }

    private void spawnBallon() {
        Rectangle ballon = new Rectangle();
        ballon.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800 - 64); //
        ballon.y = 0;
        ballon.width = 40;
        ballon.height = 80;
        ballons.add(ballon);
        lastBallonTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
    }

    private boolean ballonBursted(Rectangle ballon) {
        Vector2 touch = new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
        if (ballon.contains(touch))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.3f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        InputProcessor processor;

        camera.update();
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        game.batch.begin();
        font.draw(game.batch, "Ballon Bursted :" + ballonBursted, 0, 700);
        font.draw(game.batch, "Ballon Missed:" + ballonMissed, 275, 700);
        for (Rectangle ballon : ballons) {
            game.batch.draw(burstFrames[0], ballon.x, ballon.y);
        }

        if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastBallonTime > 1000000000) {
            spawnBallon(); // a ballon every second
        }

        Iterator<Rectangle> iter = ballons.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Rectangle ballon = iter.next();
            ballon.y = ballon.y + 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

            if (ballonBursted(ballon) == true) {
                ballonBursted++;
                game.batch.draw(burstFrames[1], ballon.x, ballon.y);
                ballonBursting.play();
                iter.remove();
            }
            else if (ballon.y + 64 > 800) {
                iter.remove();
                ballonMissed++;
            }
        }

        if (ballonMissed > 5) {
            game.setScreen(new ScoreScreen(game, ballonBursted));
        }
        game.batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        ballonFrames.dispose();
        ballonBursting.dispose();
        game.batch.dispose();

    }
```

I am using animation class of libgdx to change my image of ballon to the one where its bursted .
I am fairly new to libgdx and unable to figure out what wrong am i doing here .
Should i create a table and layout my ballon elements as actor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private boolean ballonBursted(Rectangle ballon) {
        Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        camera.unproject(touchPos);

        if (ballon.contains(touchPos.x, touchPos.y))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

please read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18555705/2158970

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right you just want to know if the touchpoint is contained in the Rectangle `ballon`. Then you could use [Rectangle#contains()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Rectangle.html#contains-float-float-) method:

```
 ballon.contains(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
```

see also the [source code of Rectangle class](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Rectangle.java)

Comment: This does not seem to work for me in my code , i think i am doing something else wrong.have edited the question with the complete code of my gameScreen where i want my ballon to burst when i click on it.

Comment: Then it is time to debug that ;-) Check the coordinates of the textures & rectangles & the touchpoint by adding a breakpoint where you check if point is inside the rectangle. Are the values what you expected?