# Why mouse click position is misplaced?

Tags: libgdx, game-engine

I'm creating a board game in libgdx using a board of 3 x 3 buttons in a Group that's in a VerticalGroup.

I have problems because the mouse position I get is misplaced from the actual position in screen. I can click a button, but the button below is clicked instead.

I'm using text buttons, so this should be an internal issue of the Actor. Can I configure it in some way to avoid this behaviour?

I found no cause for this on any forum.

Can you help me? Am I forgetting something?

Comment: You'll need to show your code for setting up your stage and resizing its viewport.

Comment: Are you unprojecting your coords? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554126/using-unproject-correctly-in-java-libgdx